# Calculating techniqes faster than calculator

Tags: education

There are some techniques for calculating faster than calculator,so I want to know some of then like dividing and multiplying which are faster.

Here is a video of competition how small children do calculation faster.https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7rkEg54HN4A

For example calculating this whitin 5 seconds or so….
$$\frac{296146931}{13873}$$

Comment: Please feel free to edit my post :)

Comment: It seems the link doesn't work possibly because of $]$ included in the hyperlink. But anyway I don't think it's possible to do computations faster than calculators, it's just that it might take more time to input instructions for them

Comment: @user160738 fixed

Comment: You surely must be aware of [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_Mathematics_(book)). But I have understood that the use of this book has been controversial.

Comment: Surely you've looked up Shakuntala Devi's books?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've heard of Arthur Benjamin but if you haven't look him up. He gave some tips on squaring numbers. So let's take something easy to square like 24. $24^2=(24+4)(24-4)+4^2$ by difference of squares and all. Now we can do 28*20+16 which is pretty easy. Another one is when the ones digits add up to 10 and the tens+ digits are the same. For example $12\cdot 18$ you add one to the tens digit and then multiply the ones digit and put them together so 216 is our answer. Another one is $19\cdot 11$ which is 209.

Comment: $24^2$ can easily done by using $(a+b)^2$ formula by taking simple numbers,and what will you say about doing this?$\frac{296146931}{13873}$

Comment: Well that I don't know sorry but I was answering another aspect of your question